# Modeling objects in Redis for maximum searchability

Tags: redis

How do you model this kind of "object" in Redis for maximum searchability?

```java
public class Item {
    Double price;
    String geoHash;
    Long startAvailabilty; // timestamp
    Long endAvailabilty; // timestamp
    Set<Keywords> keywords;
    String category;
    String dateCreated; // iso date
    String dateUpdated; // iso date
    Integer likes;
    Boolean isActive;
}
```

Where it would be possible to query any or all of the values, e.g. price range, timestamp range query from the two timestamp fields, keywords query from within an embedded set and with a Boolean value query. Sorting by ISO date, sorting by the number of likes.

Comment: Did you check the Redis Module https://redisearch.io ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis do not support complex searches directly. So I suggest split all searches to several simple searches. The `Item` model also should be split.

- save `Item` object:

1. each `Item` instance should have a unique key.
2. encode `Item` instance to a string. eg: JSON String.
3. save `Item` instance in redis with the unique key and encoded string value.

- For price range search:

1. use `ZADD`, save to sorted set with key:`PRICE_RANGE` score:`Item price value` member:`Item unique key`.
2. use `ZRANGEBYSCORE` to get members with price range.
3. iter the members(unique key of item) to get all items
4. decode all items

- For timestamp range query ...
- For ...

Hope to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Redis does not support the kind of access pattern you are looking for.

However, thanks to Redis module, you can achieve the same goal.

zeeSQL is a novel Redis module that embed a SQL database into Redis.
[zeeSQL allows to search all your data with simple and familiar SQL queries.](https://zeesql.com)

In your specific use case, I would define two tables, the table `Item` and the table `Keyword`.

On the `Keyword` table, you can put a constraint and make it a set.
The `Keyword` should have a foreign key against the `Item` table and being unique, on the tuple `(ItemID, keyword)`

At this point you can just populate your table, and look for item into them using SQL syntax, while maintaining the performance of Redis, zeeSQL works in-memory.

Another option with zeeSQL, it is to store your data in Redis as hash elements, and use [zeeSQL secondary indexes](https://doc.zeesql.com/secondary-indexes).

In this way your data reside in both Redis, for very fast access, and in zeeSQL for searchability.
On zeeSQL secondary indexes is possible to define SQL indexes to make your queries even faster.